# Elasticsearch Keyword Extraction

Tags: elasticsearch, keyword, extract, tf-idf

I have a corpus of ~10K articles.  For each article I would like to extract keywords (tags).  So for every article I would like a ranking of the tokenized terms in the article based on their frequency in the article relative to their frequency in other articles in the corpus - along the lines of TF-IDF across the complete corpus.

I am using elasticsearch (used it for the first time last week).  I'm having a hard time finding references how to do this.  I've found a number of links including this link from SO:

[Fast keyword extraction in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171211/fast-keyword-extraction-in-elasticsearch)

and this link from google forums:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/elasticsearch/1XEe_Sv8JrE/kOQnSB7riE0J

but what I am hoping to find is a clear A to Z guide (as is so often available for just about anything).

I will continue to google and look for other resources, but any advice as to resources or how to do this would be a great help!  Thank you.